# Replace only last occurrence of column value in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've a DataFrame with a `Company` column.

```
Company
-------------------------------                                                           
Tundra Corporation Art Limited
Desert Networks Incorporated
Mount Yellowhive Security Corp
Carter, Rath and Mueller Limited (USD/AC)
Barrows corporation /PACIFIC
Corporation, Mounted Security
```

I've a dictionary with regexes to normalize the company entities.

```
(^|\s)corporation(\s|$); Corp 
(^|\s)Limited(\s|$); LTD 
(^|\s)Incorporated(\s|$); INC 
...
```

I need to normalize only the last occurrence. This is my desired output.

```
Company
-------------------------------                                                           
Tundra Corporation Art LTD
Desert Networks INC
Mount Yellowhive Security Corp
Carter, Rath and Mueller LTD (USD/AC)
Barrows Corp /PACIFIC
Corp, Mounted Security
```

(Only normalize `Limited` and **not** `Corporation`  for : `Tundra Corporation Art Limited`)

My code:

```
for k, v in entity_dict.items():
    df['Company'].replace(regex=True, inplace=True, to_replace=re.compile(k,re.I), value=v)
```

Is it possible to only change the last occurrence of an entity (do i need to change my regex)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `(\s|$)` to `($)` for match end of strings:

```
entity_dict = {'(^|\s)corporation($)': ' Corp',
               '(^|\s)Limited($)': ' LTD',
               '(^|\s)Incorporated($)': ' INC'}

for k, v in entity_dict.items():
    df['Company'].replace(regex=True, inplace=True, to_replace=re.compile(k,re.I), value=v)

print (df)
                          Company
0      Tundra Corporation Art LTD
1             Desert Networks INC
2  Mount Yellowhive Security Corp
```

EDIT: You can simplify dictionary for no regex, then create lowercase dict for possible use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html), get last value of indexing `str[-1]` and [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by lowercase dict, last replace in list comprension:

```
entity_dict = {'corporation': 'Corp',
               'Limited': 'LTD',
               'Incorporated': 'INC'}

lower = {k.lower():v for k, v in entity_dict.items()}
s1 = df['Company'].str.findall('|'.join(lower.keys()), flags=re.I).str[-1].fillna('')
s2 = s1.str.lower().map(lower).fillna('')

df['Company'] = [a.replace(b, c) for a, b, c in zip(df['Company'], s1, s2)]
print (df)
                                 Company
0             Tundra Corporation Art LTD
1                    Desert Networks INC
2         Mount Yellowhive Security Corp
3  Carter, Rath and Mueller LTD (USD/AC)
4                  Barrows Corp /PACIFIC
5                 Corp, Mounted Security
```

Comment: I can't do that because sometimes it's a bit messed up and the entity is not always at the end of the string  as you would expect. I try to cleanup the data. That's why i try to normalize only the last occurrence. That gives me the desired result for now

Comment: @JohnDoe - hmmm, is possible change sample data?

Comment: @JohnDoe - I am now confused, why only first `Tundra Corporation` is not changed?

Comment: Because `Corporation` is part of the name and the entity is `Limited (LTD)`. I assume the latter is the entity. It will not fix it 100% but fine for me. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @JohnDoe - So if multiple matched values is necessary change only last one? E.g. if `Desert Limited Networks Incorporated` then need `Desert Limited Networks INC` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191212/discussion-between-jezrael-and-john-doe).

Comment: @JohnDoe - Done, many solutions was tested and last this working for me nice.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll give it a try. Just a short question. Why using `lower` while you also use `flags=re.I` ?

Comment: @JohnDoe - because `str.findall` - it matched uppercase/lowercase values by dict - here is same use both dicts `s1 = df['Company'].str.findall('|'.join(lower.keys()), flags=re.I).str[-1].fillna('')` same like `s1 = df['Company'].str.findall('|'.join(entity_dict.keys()), flags=re.I).str[-1].fillna('')`, but for `map` is necessary exact match, so used `lower` dictionary

Comment: Many thanks for your time and effort ! Works like a charm !

Comment: @JohnDoe - Supeeer, 3hours was killed, but founded solution, it is the most important :)